# Xcode 6 keyboard shortcut's, tips and tricks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi guys I am new to Xcode and iOS development environment and want to know some tips, tricks or shortcut keys which can save good amount of my development time any link, blog or answers will highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well here are few direct keyboard shortcuts and tricks you should use in Xcode 6
to execute got to X code and press simultaneously keys in bold belows

Quickly open preferences :
**Command ,**

Apple generally hides library folder  :
**click on finder->Go->Option**

Hide/Show Navigator :
**Command 0**

Hide/Show Utility :
**Command Option 0**

Hide/Show Debugger :
**Command Shift Y**

To Highlight file in the navigator :
**Command Shift J**

Move Between .h & .m :
**Control Command Up/Down**

Move courser to filter bar :
**Command Option J**

Indent Selected Code :
**Control i**

For adding/removing breakpoints to active courser line :
Command \

***Tips & Tricks***
1. make warnings and errors show in multiple lines
**Go to preferences->General->Issues Navigator Details->chose options**(Up to 10 lines)

2. Some time it irritates us when we double click and new windows get opened so to avoid that
   **Go to preferences->Navigator->Double Click Navigation-> chose options**(same as click)

3.Change fonts and colours many of us say Basic font is to small or I don’t like the colour, its very easy to customise :
**Go to preferences->Fonts & Colours->Choose option**

4. Want to have the line numbers along with the code :
   **Go to preferences->Text Editing->Click on line numbers**

Add/Remove Single line comment :
**Command /**

Search and navigate a particular word :
**Command E and then
Command G**

Jump bar for filtering methods :
**Control 0 6**

Navigate between classes :
**Control 0 5**

go ahead and try : **Control 0 4/3/2/1/0**
also Try :  **Command 0 8/7/6/5/4/3/2/1/0**

credits ray and his team
source [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85999/xcode-6-tips-tricks-tech-talk-video)

Answer (score 2):

Ray Wenderlich links

1) [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85999/xcode-6-tips-tricks-tech-talk-video)

2) [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/72021/supercharging-xcode-efficiency)

these two should get you started really helped me, after you will get to know Xcode go to

Xcode->preferences->Key Bindings

to do some customisations to the shortcuts